# Was it a theophany in Numbers 22:25?

Tags: numbers, angels, theophany

Numbers 22:25
New International Version

> When the donkey saw **the angel of the LORD**, it pressed close to the wall, crushing Balaam’s foot against it. So he beat the donkey again.

Did the donkey see a visible manifestation of God? If yes, what's the significance of this unique occurrence that God showed himself to an animal instead of to people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Robert that the story contains a number of enacted parables steeped in symbolism.

The main point of the this part of the story (Num 22:22-35) of Balaam and the donkey's theophany is the extreme irony:

- the Angel of the Lord is revealed to a mute animal (v25) and NOT the prophet.  This shows that the animal is more worthy of such a divine manifestation than the prophet
- The "dumb" animal speaks to the prophet who responds (V28-30) - this shows that the "dumb" animal is wiser than the prophet

In both cases, the perfidy and selfishness of the prophet is exposed.  It should have given him pause to think and question his motives.  However, Balaam's extreme self centeredness prevented him from fully understanding what the LORD was trying to tell him.

That this "Angel of the LORD" was very likely the LORD Himself can be seen by the clear references to Balaam's conversation with the LORD in V31-35.  Thus, the vision seen by the donkey appears to have been a true theophany.

**APPENDIX - "Angel of the LORD"**

The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself, probably Jesus in particular.  Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, Rev 8:3-5, 10:1-10, 18:1, 20:1-4.

A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.

Answer (score 2):

This story has a lot of symbolism.

Donkeys are symbols of prophets, so in that sense the Angel of the Lord only ever appears to donkeys. But the joke here is that the actual donkey was a better prophet than Balaam, who did not see the Angel of the Lord.

Thus Balaam becomes a type for stubbornness or willfulness (known in the Old Testament as being "beastly" e.g. Ps 73.22, Dan 4.25, Ps 49.12, Job 40.15), madly pursuing a dangerous course that is in conflict with God, whereas the donkey, an actual beast known for its willfulness, yields more quickly than Balaam did. Thus Balaam was the beast and the donkey was the prophet.

Moreover this metaphor of the donkey being a better prophet continues when the donkey's mouth is opened and it speaks the word to Balaam, instructing him, and as a result of the Donkey's testimony his own eyes were opened and he saw the Angel of the Lord and then he repented. Reinforcing again that the donkey was the true prophet and Balaam was the true beast. Nu 22.28-31:

> And the LORD opened the mouth of the ass, and she said unto Balaam,
> What have I done unto thee, that thou hast smitten me these three
> times? And Balaam said unto the ass, Because thou hast mocked me: I
> would there were a sword in mine hand, for now would I kill thee. And
> the ass said unto Balaam, Am not I thine ass, upon which thou hast
> ridden ever since I was thine unto this day? was I ever wont to do so
> unto thee? And he said, Nay. Then the LORD opened the eyes of Balaam,
> and he saw the angel of the LORD standing in the way, and his sword
> drawn in his hand: and he bowed down his head, and fell flat on his
> face.

Comment: Robert,
Great points you made.  It reminded me of the scripture of Jesus's entrance riding on a young  donkey when he came To Israel as their King. John 12:15

Comment: @Sherrie, yes, I was thinking of that also! The early christians called themselves "Christ-bearers", e.g. they were the donkeys (prophets) bringing Christ into the city.